# Debugging an unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, dll, windows-ce, debug-symbols

I have a solution with two projects:

Project A: is a dll that was written in C++

Project B: Is a C# application that call the dll of project A

My problem: I can't hit any break points I put into the DLL code. The break point has a message attached to it saying that "no symbols have been loaded for this document".

Notes:

- My problem is for Windows CE 6.0
- I am copying the dll and its .pdb files with a post build event to the C# app's debug execution dir into the device.

Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

After I made this question I found this post that answers my question.

[Loading Native DLL as Debug Module in Managed C# Code for Windows CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112827/loading-native-dll-as-debug-module-in-managed-c-sharp-code-for-windows-ce?rq=1)